# How to create show and hide an element in my case?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

I am having a weird issue with no-show in my app.

I have something like

```
<ul ng-click="open =!open">
    ….
</ul>
```

When I click my `ul,` I want to animate a `div` to show.

so I have

```
<div id='wrapper' ng-show='open'>
    …..
</div>
```

I was able to show and hide my `wrapper` div but I need to have animation during the transition.

so I add

```
.ng-hide {
  opacity: 1.0;
  display: block !important;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}

.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

.ng-show {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.ng-show {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Turns out the `hide` action will have a 2 second animation but not `show` action.

Can anyone help me about this issue? I really have hard time understanding it.

Thanks.

Comment: Any update on your attempts at this?

Comment: @FlyingCat: Did you try any of the solutions below ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

If you watch the DOM while hiding and show your div, you'll see that when an element is hidden, `ng-hide` is added to its class list, but there is no corresponding `ng-show` class added when the element is shown. This is why you're seeing an animation when the element is hidden but not when it's shown.

Your best bet for animation is [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate).

**Load script:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

**Inject module into app:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

**Use the ngAnimate classes:**

```
.ng-hide-add,
.ng-hide-remove {
  display:block!important;
}

.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
  transition:all linear 2s;
}

.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  transition:all linear 1s;
}

.ng-hide {
  opacity:0;
}
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Eb7uQREeEu4FhXO1WE06?p=preview)

**UPDATE:** As I see @ExpertSystem just posted similar instructions, note that my code uses 1.3 versions of Angular and ngAnimate. So, depending on which version of Angular you're using, you can quite possibly pattern your code after theirs or mine.

Answer (score 0):

`ngShow` (just like `ngHide`) adds/removes the `ng-hide` class in order to show or hide an element.

In order to enable animation with `ngHide`/`ngShow`, you need to include the `ngAnimate` module as a dependency to your app.
`ngAnimate` will add some extra classes which will enable your animation to be properly defined using CSS.

**[The docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/directive/ngShow)** have detailed instructions on how to achieve this (this is for `v1.2.16`).
Note that depending on the version of Angular, animations might need to be defined differently (e.g. things changed in `v1.3`).

The solution below is based on `v1.2.16`:

```
// HTML
<div id="wrapper" class="animate-show" ng-show='open'>...

// CSS
.animate-show {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-add,
.animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
    display: block !important;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/vxHRk/)**.